# Where is the QuantumComputing package?

Tags: quantum-computing

Where is the `QuantumComputing` package?

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wHnfWuS0C08

[image]

Comment: I think it's currently in a parallel universe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/Wolfram/QuantumFramework/

```
PacletInstall[ResourceObject["Wolfram/QuantumFramework"]]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
Needs["Wolfram`QuantumFramework`"]

?Wolfram`QuantumFramework`*
```

[image]

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer. The small benefit to the site is that when this pops up in a search, it shows that it has an answer that the OP thinks solves the problem. (Makes a difference to me when I'm deciding which rabbit trails to follow when I'm hunting for an answer.) TIA.